# Coldfusion - Get user's IP when application is behind a load balancer

Tags: coldfusion, http-headers, ip, coldfusion-10, internal-load-balancer

My coldfusion web app is located behind a load balancer. I need to get the user's ip address.
I have used the following but I am still not getting the user's ip but the load balancer's ip.

My Coldfusion version is 10.

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(GetHttpRequestData().headers, "X-Forwarded-For") >
<cfset ip = Trim(ListFirst(GetHttpRequestData().headers["X-Forwarded-For"]))  > 
<cfelse>
<cfset ip = CGI.REMOTE_ADDR >
</cfif>
```

The `GetHttpRequestData().headers` does not contain `X-Forwarded-For`.

Is there anything that I am missing? Have you experienced the same?

Comment: You have to configure your load balancer to pass that information through to the backend servers.